# How to remove clear image when backspace has fully cleared textfield?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm making a word game I have a clear text button that appears over the text field when user types a letter (any-letter):

Clear button:

```
- (IBAction)btnclear:(id)sender {
NSString *oldString = _textbox.text;
NSString *newString;
newString = [oldString substringFromIndex: _textbox.text.length];
[_textbox setText:newString];
[_textXclear setHidden:YES];
```

Image here: https://9fcf3c93-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/foreversantorini/home/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-22%20at%2015.02.48.png?attachauth=ANoY7cqysJ7x47s68f3dHMQpOmGPzwDDQ-hFotctSaKiA1OHYlZPu8BDnJEtD1oa3I3q335la9h13jZNftExDJrv7I-8WHmdbJ1mVEd-X1N50Nb3B_ogEsG2w3r2Q5SyLu-NwykqyNF4X7cocvrwkJpwYl31W26olIXPbhl0Z21j5gePDsd5lB5lJDbr1_543eUVKW9-qJOgTI-w4v2ET0vcnQw0EXbLNtQL81H1YXiyCutsPLNt426ohWUT8ooAgSXdziKdW5TE&attredirects=0

I also have a backspace button that removes letters one by one here:

```
- (IBAction)btnback:(id)sender {
NSString *backspace = _textbox.text;
int lengthofstring = backspace.length;
if(lengthofstring > 0)
backspace = [backspace substringToIndex:lengthofstring -1];
_textbox.text = backspace;
```

The problem is when the backspace button clears all the text the clear button image remains on the screen!

extra info: The property of the clear button is _textXclear

Answer (score 0):

in the textfield settings in the interface builder you can set Clear Button settings, can that solve your problem?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearButtonMode

[image]